# Code syntax highlighting for Apple Web Server (Wiki, Weblog)?

Tags: webserver, blogs, syntax-highlighting, wiki

Does anyone managed to add some nice code highlighting for the wiki and blog software that comes with the [Apple Wiki Server](http://www.apple.com/macosx/server/)? I found a [discussion on the topic](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2188373), however, without further success stories. [SyntaxHighlighter by Alex Gorbatchev](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) as mentioned in the aforementioned thread would be really nice to have.